# How can I prevent email notification send to user when authorizing calendar access

Tags: .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the V3 api of google: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Google.Apis.Calendar.v3

as an domain administrator we use the api to give other users access to an general mailbox and calendar.

When I give another user access to an calendar the user is receiving a cryptic email wiht a confirmation.

In the previous api no email was send!

How can I prevent this email, since our endusers will not understand any otf the text inside this email , during testing some of them event marked this email as spam!

This is not the way we want this from user experience perspective.

> sender of the email: serviceaccount@domain.com
>
> subject of the email: serviceaccount@domain.com has shared a calendar with you

but  in the body of the email is the real info

> Hello userx@domain.com,
>
> We are writing to let you know that serviceaccount@domain.com has
> given you access to manage events and sharing settings for the Google
> Calendar called "mailboxY@domain.com".
>
> We have automatically added this calendar to your Google Calendar
> account. You can hide or completely remove this calendar at any time.
>
> - The Google Calendar Team View Your Calendar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible in either the API or the UI to suppress these notification emails. The team is aware of the desire for this feature, but there are no updates at this time.

Comment: I want this email to be send, but I'm getting only when I'm sharing the second calendar my service account creates, not the first one which can only be added manually, any ideas?